# Dynamic Django forms

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms, django-templates

I want to create dropdown list in django forms.
One way is to get the options and pass it to the template from `views.py`
Other way is via `forms.py` but i'm not sure how to do that.Although the code to do that is available,it's not usable for me as i want to generate options depending on the user that it logged in(that means using `request` parameter).Can you suggest how to do that?
The first method of passing via `views.py` works to the extent of generating a dropdown but i'm not able to get the value of selected option from request.It gives a null value.
Here's my code:
Template

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#remove_form').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
        $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
            data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
            type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
            url: '/remove/', // the file to call
            success: function(response) { // on success..
                $('#test').html("<p style='color:green;margin-left:40%;margin-right:40%;'>Submitted!</p>"); // update the DIV

            },
            error: function(e, x, r) { // on error..
                $('#err').html(e); // update the DIV
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});

</script>

......
......

 <form method="POST" id="remove_form" action="">{% csrf_token %}
      <select id="remove">
      {% for i,p in dropdown %}      
        <option value="{{i}}">{{p}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
        </select>
        {{remove|crispy}}
         <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Remove">
</form>
```

Also note that i'm rendering this form from one view but the data goes into another view for processing via ajax call.

Comment: You seem to be asking about the solution rather than the problem... What is the dropdown list supposed to be for?

Comment: dropdown list would have courses opted by a person and this would be retrieved from the database according to the id of the user. @Sayse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select id="remove">
```

The `select` tag takes a `name` attribute.

```
<select name="remove" id="remove">
```

Then your form works. http://codepen.io/C14L/pen/dMKqPE

Comment: looks like i was making a mistake in name and id...thanks for clearing it up!